# Optimizacion SQL

Tags: sql

¿En qué orden conviene declarar una clave primaria, teniendo en cuenta que posee una clave compuesta. ¿ Y Por qué conviene ese orden?
Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

Comment: Hola Coco, bienvenido. Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para qe aprendas a formular de manera adecuada una pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: El tuyo es un escenario muy amplio, no creo que haya otra respuesta que "depende". Una estrategia, en el caso de clave compuesta por dos columnas, es analizar las consultas y ver cual de las dos columnas se usa mas como filtro de forma individual y elegir ésta en el primer lugar del índice, pero ya te digo, sin tener un caso concreto es difícil emitir una respuesta.